# What is the difference between Deep Learning and traditional Artificial Neural Network machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

Can you offer a concise explanation of the differences between [Deep Learning](https://developer.nvidia.com/deep-learning) and Traditional Machine Learning that utilize neural networks? How many levels are need to make a neural network "deep"? Is this all just marketing hype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beg to differ with @Frank Puffer's answer. I don't understand what he meant by performing an unsupervised learning procedure on the hidden layers etc.

Deep Learning refers to Neural Network models with generally more than 2 or 3 hidden layers. Most DL models have 10 to 100 or more layers.

The recent revolution in the Deep Learning models relies on two things:
1. the availability of lots of data--which is a product of the internet age
2. the availability of GPUs

The algorithm used for optimization of DL models is called the backpropagation algorithm (which is mathematically equivalent to gradient decent). Backprop actually has been around since at least the 80s--it's not a DL specific thing.

DL models generally require copious amounts of data due to the complexity and size of the models. They typically have millions of tunable weight parameters. The optimization requires high compute power because of the size of training data and the millions of partial derivatives (with respect to the weights) that need to be computed at each iteration.

In essence, Deep Learning is not a marketing hype. It's a large multi layered Neural Network model that requires lots of data and powerful GPUs to train. And once it's trained they achieve super-human accuracies at certain tasks.

Comment: I don't think there is much of a contradiction between our answers, we just highlight different aspects. My main point was that standard backprop performs poorly on networks with more than 3 layers. This is not just a matter of computing power. When naively applying backprop to a network with >10 layers it will get stuck in most cases, even for simple problems. During the last years, different improvements and tricks have been developed to overcome this issue. One of them is the unsupervised pre-training I mentioned. It is true that it has been found to be less useful than originally thought.

Comment: @FrankPuffer. I'm not sure how effective and widely used _unsupervised pre-training_ is. But that's not necessarily what makes DL possible.  Whereas, some architectural innovations like using ReLUs (<=probably the primary reason that made backprop work on models with more than 3 layers) and skip connections (eg. _ResNet_ & _LSTMs_) have made the backprop training work well, and might be added to the list. There are also other architectural designs (like _Batch_ _normalization_ or _Xavier_ _initialization_) that help train deeper models but we shouldn't get into them at this post.

Comment: Right, it seems like unsupervised pre-training became less popular recently, in favor of the other techniques you mentioned. I have therefore edited my answer. By the way, I find your comment much more appropriate than your original answer because hardware performance and availability of data would be mostly useless if we still used the same network architectures as 30 years ago.

Comment: In ML we have to do feature engineering hand coded  but in DL we dont have to do feature engineering, model will learn important features by itself.

Answer (score 11):

The standard backpropagation algorithm (gradient descent) gets serious issues when the number of layers becomes large. The probability of local minima in the error function increases with every layer. Not only local minima in a mathematical sense cause problems, sometimes there are just flat regions in the error function (modifying one or more weights does not significantly change the error) where gradient descent does not work.

On the other hand, networks with many layers can solve more difficult problems, as every layer of cells can also provide a layer of abstraction.

Deep Learning addresses exactly this problem. The basic idea is to perform an unsupervised learning procedure on every single layer in addition to using gradient descent for the network as a whole. The goal of the unsupervised learning is to make each single layer extract characteristic features out of its input that can be used by subsequent layers.

Although the term "Deep Learning" is currently being used much too widely, it is more than just a marketing hype.

*Edit: A few years ago, many people, including myself, believed that unsupervised pre-training was the main enabler of deep learning. Since then, other techniques became popular that produce even better results in many cases. As mentioned in the comment by @Safak Okzan (below his own answer), these include:*

- *Residual Networks*
- *Batch normalization*
- *Rectified linear units*

Comment: Thanks! That is just the type of explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In recent years, the models developed to solve various machine learning problems have become far more complex, with a very large number of layers.  For example, Google's Inception-v3 model has (I think) 42 layers. Traditional neural networks used to typically use only a handful of hidden layers.  The term "Deep" used in the context of "Deep Learning" and "Deep Convolutional Neural Nets" is a nod to the substantial # of layers involved.

Comment: Right, but I'd say this answer misses the main point: You cannot simply add more and more layers while still using traditional learning algorithms like backpropagation. This simply does not work. But fortunately some clever guys came up with improved learning algorithms. And someone found a flashy name for this: "Deep Learning".

Comment: I agree with your central point, and actually I would recommend the poster accept your answer.  On the other hand, it's actually quite incredible how much the core training algorithms haven't changed - deep convolutional neural nets for example employ a very different connectivity structure, and yet we still use minor variations on stochastic gradient descent and backpropagation for training them.  I would say that the biggest changes are in the structure of the layers and the various techniques developed to deal with overfitting (for example, convolutional layers and dropout respectively).

Answer (score 1):

From application perspective, I would differentiate between the neural networks used in DL and ML on the following lines:

- **Number of Layers** - Simple neural networks have lesser number of hidden layers( generally within 10) whereas Deep neural nets can have larger number of hidden layers ( as mentioned above 10 to 100 or beyond).
- **Purpose** - Deep Learning has specialized neural networks(in terms of architecture) which can be used for specific tasks such as CNNs for image analysis, RNNs/LSTMs for sequences etc. Simple neural networks can be used for tasks such as Linear Regression, Classification(single/multi class).
- **Processing Complexity** - Training a Deep Learning model requires more data and computational resources than the traditional Machine Learning neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional Artificial Neural Network deals with less number of hidden layers whereas the deep learning deals with many hidden layers close to 1000.
for example : In both of them you have an input layer which is passed onto different layers like layer 1, 2 and so on. In the case of deep learning you have more hidden layers and hence there will be more weights that you need to compute and update while performing backtracking and in ANN the weights would be fairly less.