# Neural Networks - Difference between deep autoencoder and stacked autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

Disclaimer: I also posted this question on CrossValidated but it is not receiving any attention. If this is not the place for it I will gladly remove it.

As I understand it, the only difference between them is the way the two networks are trained. Deep autoencoders are trained in the same way as a single-layer neural network, while stacked autoencoders are trained with a greedy, layer-wise approach. Hugo Larochelle confirms this in the comment of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5ZYm_wJ37c). I wonder if this is the ONLY difference, any pointers?

Comment: The only difference is how they are trained, also has been noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52221103/3736955. In Stacked AE, layer wise training is done, and when comparing loss of 2nd layer, comparison is done with output of 1st layer, not with input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terminology in the field isn't fixed, well-cut and clearly defined and different researches can mean different things or add different aspects to the same terms. Example discussions:

- [What is the difference between Deep Learning and traditional Artificial Neural Network machine learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578634/what-is-the-difference-between-deep-learning-and-traditional-artificial-neural-n) (some people think that 2 layers is deep enough, some mean 10+ or 100+ layers).
- [Multi-layer perceptron vs deep neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315402/multi-layer-perceptron-vs-deep-neural-network) (mostly synonyms but there are researches that prefer one vs the other).

As for AE, according to various sources, *deep autoencoder* and *stacked autoencoder* are **exact synonyms**, e.g., here's a quote from ["Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052289.do):

> Just like other neural networks we have discussed, autoencoders can
>   have multiple hidden layers. In this case they are called stacked
>   autoencoders (or deep autoencoders).

Later on, the author discusses two methods of training an autoencoder and uses both terms interchangeably.

I would agree that the *perception* of the term "stacked" is that an autoencoder can extended with new layers without retraining, but this is actually true regardless of how existing layers have been trained (jointly or separately). Also regardless of the training method, the researches may or may not call it *deep enough*. So I wouldn't focus too much on terminology. It can stabilize some day but not right now.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if you indirectly mention it at your answer but I have the impression that the terms stacked autoencoders and deep autoncoders are not used interchangeably since deep autoencoders are like `input_layer->hidden_layer_1->hidden_layer_2->...->output_layer` while stacked autoencoders are like `input_layer_1->hidden_layer_1->output_layer_1->input_layer_2->hidden_layer_2->output_layer_2` where in the latter case each of the autoencoders has as targets the output of the previous autoencoder. Let me know your thoughts on my comment.

Comment: Can you comment on @PoeteMaudit his answer? Because I have the same interpretation and want to know if this is correct or not