# Train Stacked Autoencoder Correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I try to build a Stacked Autoencoder in Keras (tf.keras). By **stacked** I do not mean **deep**. All the examples I found for Keras are generating e.g. 3 encoder layers, 3 decoder layers, they train it and they call it a day. However, it seems the correct way to train a **Stacked** Autoencoder (SAE) is the one described in this paper: [Stacked Denoising Autoencoders: Learning Useful Representations in
a Deep Network with a Local Denoising Criterion](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/vincent10a/vincent10a.pdf)

In short, a SAE should be trained layer-wise as shown in the image below. After layer 1 is trained, it's used as input to train layer 2. The reconstruction loss should be compared with the layer 1 **and not the input layer**.

[image]

And here is where my trouble begins. How to tell Keras which layers to use the loss function on?

Here is what I do. Since the Autoencoder module is not existed anymore in Keras, I build the first autoencoder, and I set its encoder's weights (`trainable = False`) in the 1st layer of a second autoencoder with 2 layers in total. Then when I train that, it obviously compares the reconstructed layer `out_s2` with the input layer `in_s`, instead of the layer 1 `hid1`.

```
# autoencoder layer 1
in_s = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_size,))
noise = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(in_s)
hid = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes[0], activation='relu')(noise)
out_s = tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(hid)

ae_1 = tf.keras.Model(in_s, out_s, name="ae_1")
ae_1.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

# autoencoder layer 2
hid1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes[0], activation='relu')(in_s)
noise = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(hid1)
hid2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes[1], activation='relu')(noise)
out_s2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nodes[0], activation='sigmoid')(hid2)

ae_2 = tf.keras.Model(in_s, out_s2, name="ae_2")
ae_2.layers[0].set_weights(ae_1.layers[0].get_weights())
ae_2.layers[0].trainable = False

ae_2.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

The solution should be fairly easy, but I can't see it nor find it online. How do I do that in Keras?

Comment: Just note that the paper you are referring to is from 2010 and massively outdated. Nobody really does layer-wise training anymore. Are doing this just for fun?

Comment: So @xdurch0 how else to stack layers if not with layer-wise training? Can you give me an example or point me to a source? It is part of a big side project, but not for fun.

Comment: "Stacking" layers really just means using a deep network/autoencoder. So just train it in one go with the loss based on the initial inputs and final outputs. Layer-wise training and "stacking" was done because a few years ago people didn't know how to train deep networks. With the advent of things like relu activations, batch normalization etc. it's not worth the effort to do layer-wise training (IMHO).

Comment: This tutorial is a great example about autoencoder and is written in keras https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Comment: @xdurch0 thanks for your input, it seems you are right. I found this paper, which cleared out most of my questions "Is Joint Training Better for Deep Auto-Encoders?" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1380.pdf

Comment: @Robert I've seen this tutorial before, but it didn't really explain why they do not using stacking anymore. I found what I was looking for in the paper I posted above.

Comment: @xdurch0 I'm coming to this late, but one reason for using stacked autoencoders is for automatic feature extraction for use in a secondary algorithm for, e.g., change detection in a noisy time series. The latent space for each AE in the stack represents more and more abstract features as your stack gets deeper (deeper wrt stacks, not layers). I would also like to know how to train stack-by-stack in Keras.

Comment: Looks like the paper that the OP linked in his comment shows end-to-end training is viable for my use case too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the question is outdated by looking at the comments. But I'll still answer this as the use-case mentioned in this question is not just specific to autoencoders and might be helpful for some other cases.

So, when you say "train the whole network layer by layer", I would rather interpret it as "train small networks with one single layer in a sequence".

Looking at the code posted in this question, it seems that the OP has already built small networks. **But both these networks do not consist of one single layer.**

The second autoencoder here, takes as input the input of first autoencoder. But, it should actually take as input, the output of first autoencoder.

So then, you train the first autoencoder and collect it's predicitons after it is trained. Then you train the second autoencoder, which takes as input the output (predictions) of first autoencoder.

Now let's focus on this part: "After layer 1 is trained, it's used as input to train layer 2. The reconstruction loss should be compared with the layer 1 and not the input layer."

Since the network takes as input the output of layer 1 (autoencoder 1 in OP's case), it will be comparing it's output with this. The task is achieved.

But to achieve this, you will need to write the `model.fit(...)` line which is missing in the code provided in the question.

Also, just in case you want the model to calculate loss on input layer, you simply replace the `y` parameter in `model,fit(...)` to the input of autoencoder 1.

In short, you just need to decouple these autoencoders into tiny networks with one single layer and then train them as you wish. No need to use `trainable = False` now, or else use it as you wish.